# Image tearing in RecyclerView only for first image

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using standard recycler view and sometimes only on first image I see image tearing as shown in screen capture below. [image: Image With Issues]
 I am not using any isoteric option for imageView.

The image itself is being cropped with android:scaleType="centerCrop".

Any ideas why only first image in RecyclerView might be tearing up?

The layout of the Image is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_spacing"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_spacing"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_spacing"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/photo_collection">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_photos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: A little bit of code could help us know whats happening under the hood.

Comment: why not use scaleType="centerInside" ?

Comment: maybe some padding or margin on the `RecyclerView` ?